# loading a datagridview and adding comboboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview, ado.net

Here is a method I am using to create a datagridview and then add 2 comboboxes. Three DataTables get loaded from other classes.

```
public void GetWorkorderItems()
        {
        Workorders wo = new Workorders();
        ItemTable = wo.LoadWorkorderItemsTable(_ID);


        this.datagridWorkorderItems.DataSource = ItemTable;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Qty";
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[1].Width = 100;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Part";
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[2].Width = 100;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Labor";
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[3].Width = 100;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Price";
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[4].Width = 150;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Description";
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[5].Width = 150;

        Parts part = new Parts();
        DataTable partdata = new DataTable();
        partdata = part.LoadPartTable();
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn pcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[2];
        pcb.DataSource = partdata;
        pcb.DisplayMember = "PartName";
        pcb.ValueMember = "PartID";
        datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(pcb);

        Labor labor = new Labor();
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        data = labor.LoadLaborTable();
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[3];
        cb.DataSource = data;
        cb.DisplayMember = "LaborItem";
        cb.ValueMember = "LaborID";
        datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(cb);

        }
```

When the code gets to the creation of the DataGridViewComboBox object the code exits the method and does not add or load the comboboxes. There is no exception thrown either.

Any help?

EDIT**********
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col0 = (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[0];
            this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "WOItemID";
            this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(col0);

```
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col1 = (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[1];
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Qty";
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[1].Width = 100;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(col1);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn pcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[2];
        pcb.DataSource = partdata;
        pcb.DisplayMember = "PartName";
        pcb.ValueMember = "PartID";
        datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(pcb);
```

This might be the way to build the columns if I understand.

****Fixed code that works***************

```
public void GetWorkorderItems()
        {
        Workorders wo = new Workorders();
        ItemTable = wo.LoadWorkorderItemsTable(_ID);

        Parts part = new Parts();
        DataTable partdata = new DataTable();
        partdata = part.LoadPartTable();

        Labor labor = new Labor();
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        data = labor.LoadLaborTable();


        this.datagridWorkorderItems.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col0 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col0.DataPropertyName = "WOItemID";
        col0.Visible = false;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(col0);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col1.DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
        col1.HeaderText = "Qty";
        col1.Width = 100;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(col1);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        col2.DataPropertyName = "PartID";
        col2.DataSource = partdata;
        col2.DisplayMember = "PartName";
        col2.ValueMember = "PartID";
        col2.HeaderText = "Part";
        datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(col2);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col3 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        col3.DataPropertyName = "LaborID";
        col3.DataSource = data;
        col3.DisplayMember = "LaborItem";
        col3.ValueMember = "LaborID";
        col3.HeaderText = "Labor";
        datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(col3);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col4.DataPropertyName = "Price";
        col4.HeaderText = "Price";
        col4.Width = 100;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(col4);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col5 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col5.DataPropertyName = "Description";
        col5.HeaderText = "Description";
        col5.Width = 100;
        this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(col5);

        this.datagridWorkorderItems.DataSource = ItemTable;

        }
```

Comment: Okay one thing I see that immediately stands out is that you are auto generating columns (that is usually a dangerous thing to do unless you want textboxes.) After the columns are generated, you then take one of the columns (without checking it's type) and cast it to datagridview column. You should us an "if (col is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) { ... }" to avoid errors. I am willing to bet it fails because you are readding an existing column. Try doing this without autogenerating the columns.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin Danger Johnson. So basically as I set up properties for the columns should I just generate all the column types beforehand? That seems to make sense.

Comment: hold on, let me see if I can program an answer.

Comment: See my updated question for a possible solution?

Comment: you are still pulling columns from your datagrid view and then readding them. I don't think it will work. I just finished testing a simple example, see my answer.

Comment: what I mean about readding is you have do the following:
<p>
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col1 = (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns[1];
</p>
<p>
this.datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(col1);
</p>
and I am almost certain C# will faint at the sight of adding a column that is already within its collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public ExampleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        datagridWorkorderItems.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn qtyColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        qtyColumn.DataPropertyName = "Qty";
        qtyColumn.HeaderText = "Qty";
        datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(qtyColumn);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn partColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        partColumn.Items.Add(new Part() { ID = 0, PartName = "Tire" });
        partColumn.Items.Add(new Part() { ID = 1, PartName = "Motor" });
        partColumn.HeaderText = "Part";
        partColumn.DataPropertyName = "PartID";
        partColumn.ValueMember = "ID";
        partColumn.DisplayMember = "PartName";
        datagridWorkorderItems.Columns.Add(partColumn);

        List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();
        workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder() { Qty = 0, PartID = 0});
        workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder() { Qty = 2, PartID = 1});

        datagridWorkorderItems.DataSource = workOrders;
    }
}

public class WorkOrder
{
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public int PartID { get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see what you are doing and it makes sense. What if I need to bind to a DataTable and load my combo boxes from a data source. Would simply binding the datagridview to a datatable generate the columns? If I create the columns in code, how do I tell the datagridview to order the new columns? Does it add and display the column collection in the order of column creation?

Comment: as long as you set AutoGenerateColumns to false, they will not generate. You can bind a DataTable, just make sure the "DataPropertyName" is set to the feild to pull the data from. When you use a databind on the combobox item set "ValueMember" to the value of the item (what you will store in the field set by DataPropertyName) and "DisplayMemeber" to the text that the item will show. And now I am out to lunch, I'll check back in an hour to see if you have more questions.

Comment: Cool this makes sense. I will wire it up and post back.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! I appreciate the time you took in your answer. I posted my fixed code in my question.

Comment: No problem. When databinding to datagirdviews it is important to remember the limitations of AutoGenerateColumns. It can only generate basic types that don't require extra information such as TextBoxColumn and CheckBoxColumn, but it can't to things like ComboBoxColumn or ButtonColumn.